# jquery ajax call not reaching to spring mvc controller

Tags: spring

***I have gone through similar question, but not able to figure out why my code is not working. Please point out what mistake is in my code. The problem is jquery ajax call is not reaching to spring mvc controller***

**I am using 
Spring 3.2 and jackson 1.9**

***QuestionnaireController.java***

```
@Controller
public class QuestionnaireController {

    public QuestionnaireController()
    {
        super();
    }   

        @RequestMapping(value="/getQnrList.do")
        public @ResponseBody Message getMessage(@RequestParam String inputMessage) 
                {
          Message message = new Message();
          message.setMessage("I was sent the message : " + inputMessage + " : so I returned.");
          return message;
        }
}
```

***questionnaireList.jsp***

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/json.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function queClick()
{
        $.ajax({
    url:"getQnrList.do",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {inputMessage : 'hello'},
    success: function()
        {
            alert("hola");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error:" + textStatus + " - exception:" + errorThrown);
            }
    }); 
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Questionnaire test</p>
<input type="button" value="Get Questionnaire!" onClick="queClick()">
</body>
</html>
```

***jar files on classpath***

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/commons-fileupload-1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/commons-io-1.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/commons-lang3-3.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.11.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/jstl-1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/log4j-1.2.15.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/mongo-2.10.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/servlet-api.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/slf4j-simple-1.7.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/spring-context-support-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/spring-data-commons-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/spring-data-mongodb-1.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/spring-data-mongodb-cross-store-1.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/spring-data-mongodb-log4j-1.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/spring-tx-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Questionnaire1.0 libs/spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
```

***web.xml***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-  app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>QuestionnaireTEST</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>questionnaireList.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>qnr</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>qnr</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Questionnaire/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/rf_applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
      </context-param>
    </web-app>
```

***rf_applicationContext.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">

    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ref"></context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties"></context:property-    placeholder>
    <import resource="rf_spring-data.xml" />
</beans>
```

***FireBug Error message***

404 Not Found - `http://localhost:8080/Questionnaire/getQnrList.do? {%22inputMessage%22:%22hello%22}"`

***I am not able to catch where the mistake is***

Comment: is `Questionnaire` your context patch? what does the server log says?

Comment: Is QuestionnaireController.java in default package  or inside com.ref ?

Comment: Can you reach the page without the ajax call? Just point your URL to `http://localhost:8080/Questionnaire/getQnrList.do` and see if you can even reach the page. If not, it's a configuration problem

Comment: @PhD i am not able to reach the page http://localhost:8080/Questionnaire/getQnrList.do. And yes it is configuration problem, but not able to find it.

Comment: yes Questionnaire is context path. QuestionnaireController.java is inside com.ref package.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you dont have the url pattern .do in web.xml

add this

```
  <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>qnr</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Again your success function will not be called as the function do not have the parameter change your `success: function()` to `success: function(data)`

Comment: Thanks a lot it work!! And sorry for my stupidity, i should have figured it out mapping is not correct.

Comment: Again your success function will not be called as the function do not have the parameter change your success: function() to success: function(data). If it worked accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try setting the url to this and see:

```
url: "http://localhost:8080/Questionnaire/getQnrList.do",
```

Maybe the url is incorrect..

Comment: yes tried out that too, it did not work out. application context is **Questionnaire** and @requestMapping is **/getQnrList.do**, but not able to figure out the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do to get around this issue is to verify your dispatcher servlet file to ensure the parameters like url mapping.

Apart from that, you can try giving @RequestMapping after @Controller and write a small GET method with some log entries within the controller and see if the ajax call reaches the controller(if not the intended method within the controller). Once you confirm that you will get a better idea of what the root cause of the issue is.